# display function does not show output in pySpark with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pyspark, stream, jupyter-notebook, display

Please tell me why my code have not error but result not produce streaming query with `display()` function ?

This is how I read the data:

```
streamingInputDF = (`spark.readStream.schema(Schema1).csv("C:/Users/X550/Desktop/sadegh2")
```

Applied model pre-creation:

```
stream = cvModel.transform(streamingInputDF)
```

And here is the query:

```
streamPredictions = (stream.groupBy("Survived", "prediction").count().sort("Survived", "prediction"))
```

The following is the result:

```
streamPredictions.isStreaming------->output is True
display(streamPredictions)---------->only show col name without value
```

Comment: You mentioned that you're coding in Jupyter Notebook. It seems like you're trying to use Databricks-specific function display, which is not a part of standard PySpark API. Use show() (optionally with limit) instead.

Comment: I am trying with show() but show() does not work with stream data prediction model and give this error "query should be run with writestream.start()

Comment: Have you actually started your stream? I cannot see this in the mentioned code. Please check some tutorial on using structured streaming, e.g. here: http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/introduction-to-spark-structured-streaming-part-5/